# Improve the performance of nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, for-loop

I have `A`, which is a very large quadratic `numpy` matrix of size `n` in upper triangular form with non-negative entries above the diagonal.

How can I improve the performance of the following nested for-loops as much as possible:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,1,6],[0,0,1]],float)
n = len(A)

for k in range(1,n-1):
    for i in zip(*np.where(A[:,k]>0)):
        for j in zip(*np.where(A[k,:]>0)):
            if (A[i,j] < A[i,k]*A[k,j]):
                A[i,j]=A[i,k]*A[k,j]
```

Also not using for-loops at all would be fine for me, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one obvious small improvement are the lines:

```
if A[i, j] < A[i, k] * A[k, j]:
    A[i, j] = A[i, k] * A[k, j]
```

which can be improved to this:

```
aux = A[i, k] * A[k, j]
if A[i, j] < aux:
    A[i, j] = aux
```

---

Testing the two versions:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f1(use_float, size):
    if use_float:
        A = np.random.rand(size, size)
    else:
        A = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, (size, size))

    n = len(A)

    for k in range(1, n-1):
        for i in zip(*np.where(A[:, k] > 0)):
            for j in zip(*np.where(A[k, :] > 0)):
                if A[i, j] < A[i, k] * A[k, j]:
                    A[i, j] = A[i, k] * A[k, j]

def f2(use_float, size):
    if use_float:
        A = np.random.rand(size, size)
    else:
        A = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, (size, size))

    for k in range(1, len(A) - 1):
        for i in zip(*np.where(A[:, k] > 0)):
            for j in zip(*np.where(A[k, :] > 0)):
                aux = A[i, k] * A[k, j]
                if A[i, j] < aux:
                    A[i, j] = aux

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup = 'from __main__ import f{f} as f'
    statement = 'f({use_float}, {size})'

    number = 1000
    for use_float in (False, True):
        for size in [5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000]:
            statement = statement.format(use_float=use_float, size=size)
            t1 = timeit.timeit(statement, setup.format(f=1), number=number)
            t2 = timeit.timeit(statement, setup.format(f=2), number=number)

            print('type {:5s} | size {:6d} | t1 {:8.4f} | t2 {:8.4f} | new vs old time {:5.2f} %'.format(
                'float' if use_float else 'int',
                size, t1, t2, t2 * 100 / t1))
```

This gives us the following results:

```
type int   | size      5 | t1   0.9130 | t2   0.7245 | new vs old time 79.35 %
type int   | size     50 | t1   0.9120 | t2   0.7278 | new vs old time 79.80 %
type int   | size    500 | t1   0.9048 | t2   0.7345 | new vs old time 81.17 %
type int   | size   5000 | t1   0.9340 | t2   0.7247 | new vs old time 77.59 %
type int   | size  50000 | t1   0.9148 | t2   0.7408 | new vs old time 80.99 %
type float | size      5 | t1   0.9141 | t2   0.7373 | new vs old time 80.66 %
type float | size     50 | t1   0.9212 | t2   0.7438 | new vs old time 80.74 %
type float | size    500 | t1   0.9481 | t2   0.7383 | new vs old time 77.86 %
type float | size   5000 | t1   0.9332 | t2   0.7393 | new vs old time 79.22 %
type float | size  50000 | t1   0.9267 | t2   0.7450 | new vs old time 80.39 %
```

showing an improvement of about `20%`, which in my opinion is quite meaningful if you are looking to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

### You could use a compiler

In this example I use `Numba`, but a `Cython` solution would also be possible.

**Creating some data**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

A=np.random.rand(200*200).reshape(200,200)
A*=2
A=np.triu(A, k=0)
```

**Code**

Keep the code as simple as possible (avoid things like zip,itertools, list comprehensions, lists in general...)

```
@nb.njit()
def calc(A):
  n = len(A)

  for k in range(1,n-1):
    for i in range(n):
      if A[i,k]>0:
        for j in range(n):
          if A[k,j]>0:
            val=A[i,k]*A[k,j]
            if (A[i,j] < val):
              A[i,j]=val
  return A
```

**Performance**

```
non-compiled: 14.7 s
compiled    : 3.3  ms (the first call has an overhead of about 0.5s due to compilation)
```

Comment: Also possible (cleaner): `from numba import njit`, then `@njit`. Also, no need to calculate `A[i,k]*A[k,j]` twice, you can store in a variable and use twice.